# Click a button element on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, ui-automation

I'm trying to auto-click a button to initiate a function when the html page loads. I've tried `document.getElementById('watchButton').click` and it doesn't seem to work, the button is not clicked. Any suggestions?

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="action-area ch30">
            <button class="button dh" id="watchButton">Start Geolocation Watch</button>
            <button class="button dh" id="refreshButton" >Refresh Geolocation</button>
        </div>
```

The javascript:

```
    run:function() {
    var that = this;
    document.getElementById("watchButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
        that._handleWatch.apply(that, arguments);
    }, false); 
    document.getElementById("refreshButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
        that._handleRefresh.apply(that, arguments);
    }, false);
},
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I'd put it inside document.ready (so it doesn't fire until the DOM loads) and use jQuery syntax:

```
$(function() {
    $('#watchButton').click();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/kVJVe/

Here's the same fiddle using jQuery syntax: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/kVJVe/4

That said, why not just name your function and call it directly?

Comment: I added the following to my page `<head>` however it still doesn't `click`

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript"> 
         $(document).ready(function() { $(function() {
    $('#watchButton').click();
}); });
        </script>`

Comment: It may have been `run:`. What's that for?

Answer (score 7):

It would be `click()` not `click`

```
document.getElementById("watchButton").click();
```

You would need to call it onload or after the function has run

Comment: I also tried incorporating this at `<body onload=document.getElementById("watchButton").click();>` and had no success. Any more ideas?

Comment: well you are missing quotes. What error do you have in the console?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function () {
document.getElementById("watchButton").click(); };
```

Try this ^^

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try **trigger**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#watchButton").trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

Comment: It's not trigger() that'll do it, but your document.ready wrapper.

Comment: I tried this but it's still not initiating anything. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("studyOne").click();
$("#studyOne").trigger('click');
```

Put this in onload function. It worked for me.