# How auto click a button in iframe after page is loaded?

Tags: button, iframe, click

I loaded a page with an iframe inside a webpage of my site.
Now, I need to auto click the button into the iframe, after the page is loaded.

The button code is:

```
<button type="button" id="submit-button" class="btn trusted-commit-payment">pay now!</button>
```

Can anyone tell me the code to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click a button element on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418915/click-a-button-element-on-page-load)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help.

> Javascript

```
document.getElementById("myframe").addEventListener('load', function() {
            document.getElementById("submit-button").click();
  });
```

> JQuery

```
$('iframe').on('load',function(){
    $('#submit-button').click();
});
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142837/capture-iframe-load-complete-event)

Comment: Look at the answer again, I've made some changes.

Comment: wow, thank you so much, I will try this code tomorrow and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Last question: If the button is disabled and not visible this code works? then the button is clicked anyway? Many thanks, if this code will work i'll mark your reply as the solution.

Comment: and the page needs to be onfocus for the code to works?