# Programmatically go to a site and click a button using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a link, and this link will automatically refer to google.com and click their HTML button

**Google Search Button code:**

```
<input value="Google Search" aria-label="Google Search" name="btnK" type="submit" jsaction="sf.chk">
```

How can such be done in a link using javascript?

Comment: It's not possible to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something in JQuery, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418915/click-a-button-element-on-page-load):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $(function() { 
            $("button[aria-label='Google Search']").click(); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I want it inside a link if possible. Like you could do something such as             javascript: //code goes here. in the URL search bar.